# C: Loading a file name into a structure via argv[] but I don't want the filetype (e.g., .txt)?

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list, argv

I'm trying to create a data-structure:

```
typedef struct node_ {
    char* fName;
    char* lName;
    char* origin;
    char* destination;
    int seatNumber;

    struct node_* next;
} Seat;
```

by scanning in lines from .txt documents. The origin is the name of the document, e.g., chicago.txt.

I've just been sending argv[i] (which, again, was the name of the file, e.g., chicago.txt) to my function for the origin. Which has worked, but...

Now I need to check to see if the origin is the destination, but the destination is not formatted with .txt. (e.g., chicago.txt != chicago). I considered using strncmp for the first 3 letters or so, but that doesn't seem like a great solution. Is there a simple way to mod the argv[] to not contain .txt before sending it to the function in question? Or is there a better way to solve this that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try altering the arguments passed. Copy them to a local variable first. This example removes the .txt extension from the argument provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char fname [100];

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *xptr;

    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    strncpy (fname, argv[1], 99);
    strlwr (fname);
    xptr = strstr (fname, ".txt");
    strncpy (fname, argv[1], 99);       // copy arg again to restore orig case
    if (xptr != NULL)
        *xptr = 0;                      // truncate string
    printf ("%s\n", fname);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code block: if (xptr != NULL) {
        strncpy (fname, argv[1], 99);   // copy arg with orig case
        *xptr = 0;                      // terminate string;
    } should be: strncpy (fname, argv[1], 99 );  if( NULL != xptr ) { *xptr = 0; }  so that all string formats retain their original case

Comment: @user3629249 thank you, I have edited the code, so the file name case is restored whether or not ".txt" was found. It's a pity there isn't a `stristr()` library function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) modify anything, it is easy to just check the characters you care about, as shown below:

Given `str1` is the string with a `.` and `str2` is the one we want to compare:

```
int result = 0; // will be 1 if same
char *found;

found = strchr(str1,'.');
if (found)
{
   if (strncmp(str1,str2,found-str1) == 0)
     result = 1;
}
```

Note I did not test so you might need to add 1 to the expression `found-str1`

How this works:  In C you can do pointer arithmetic strchr finds where the `.` is and we then figure out how long a string to compare with strncmp.

Comment: Use `strrchr()` as there might be another `'.'` in the filename

Comment: And what if `str2` is longer?

Comment: not clear to me from the requirements @WeatherVane - it might be he only wants to compare to the first period in all cases.  But strrchr would work to remove an extension for sure.

Comment: @Dmitri - that was not covered in the requirements, I think if such cases would ever matter then an extra if statement should be added to check.

Comment: Consider, for example, `str1 = "york.txt"` and `str2 = "yorkton"`... should those really match?

Comment: @Dmitri - I understood your concern.  I believe they do by the OP's requirements.  Please show me where he covers that case in the question.